# POST data to MVC-Controller is null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, post, .net-7.0

I have a MVC-Project, with a simple Controller and a View.

I'm trying to make a POST request from the JavaScript to the Controller, but for some reason, the arguments are `null`.

C#:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace Tester.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public string SendData1([FromBody]string data)
        {
            // data is null!
            return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { got = data });
        }
    }
}
```

Index.cshtml

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

<div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4">Welcome</h1>
    <p>Learn about <a href="https://docs.microsoft.com/aspnet/core">building Web apps with ASP.NET Core</a>.</p>
</div>

<script>
    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ()=>{
        document.getElementById('send').addEventListener('click', ()=>{
            const text = document.getElementById('text').value;

            const path = window.location.origin;
            fetch(path + '/Home/SendData1', {
                method: 'post',
                credentials: "include",
                headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({ data: text })
            })
            .then(x => x.json())
            .then(console.log);
        })
    })
</script>

<div>
    <input type="text" id="text" />
    <button type="button" id="send">Send</button>
</div>
```

This kinda works, I get a response in the frontend, but it prints `{ "got": null }`. Obviously, if I stop the C# code with a breakpoint, it also says "null" for the parameter. I have tried different Attributes like `[FromForm]`, but no success.

How can I make this work?

Comment: What happens when you change "string data" into "object data"?

Comment: Also: debug your api endpoint with postman, try fiddling with the object structure and debug the result in your controller.

Comment: Are you sure `document.getElementById('text').value` is not `null` or `undefined`?

Comment: @Alexander yes I am

Answer (score 0):

you will have to wrap your string into object if you want to use json content type , in this case you will have to create an extra custom class. It will be  much more simple to use by default  contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8'. You don't need to include it in ajax since it is by default.

So remove completely headers

```
  headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/json",
           },
```

and remove JSON.stringify from body

```
 body: new URLSearchParams({
        data: text  
        })
```

and remove [FromBody] from your action, it will be using [FromForm] by default also.

Comment: Interessting approach. I just tried it. I get a 400 "One or more validation errors occurred." error, with the link: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1 . Also, in the "Networking"-Tab, I see that the sent data is `[object Object]` - because the JSON.stringify is gone.

Comment: @RamziKhahil Sorry, you were right about body.  I was tested using ajax jquery, but fetch uses another syntax for body, pls try my updated answer

Comment: Sorry, this is also giving me the 400 error. But I have a solution that I wrote here. I'm happy with that. Thanks a lot for your time! :)

Answer (score -2):

Thanks to the comment from Enrico, I solved it. Turns out, there is some behind the sences validation going on, that was not able to match my string to any object.

So, if I change the argument type in `SendData1([FromBody]string data)` to object. I get a `ValueKind = Object : "{"data":"asdf"}"`. After I tried creating a model, and that worked out of the box.

So, this is my current solution:

TestModel.cs

```
namespace Tester.Models
{
    public class TestModel
    {
        public string Data { get; set; }
    }
}
```

In the C#:

```
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("/Home/SendData2")]
        public string SendData1(TestModel myTest)
        {
            return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { got = myTest.Name });
        }
```

In the cshtml:

```
            fetch(path + '/Home/SendData2', {
                method: 'post',
                credentials: "include",
                  headers: {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({ Name: "test model name" })
          })
                .then(x => x.json())
                .then(x => console.log('---', x));
```

---

This works like a charm. That said, I guess that because of the validation, there is no way to just get a string "on the go". At least not in the POST data. There is an option to add it in the URL, for that see [Tutorial: Create a minimal API with ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/min-web-api?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio)